# ag-grid infinite row model with vue 3

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, vue-composition-api, ag-grid-vue

I'm trying to implement ag-grid infinite row model into a Vue3 with composition API app but even when I'm able to retrieve rows from the API and load them when the grid is initialized the table won't show the scrollbar on the grid and won't retrieve more rows from the API. The grid should render 20 rows and then after that trigger the getRows function in order to lazy load the rest of the rows (100 is just an example).

Any help will be really appreciated.

```
<template>
  <div style="height: 100%" class="test-container">
    <ag-grid-vue
      :icons="icons"
      class="ag-theme-alpine"
      domLayout="autoHeight"
      id="myGrid"
      :columnDefs="columnDefs.value"
      unSortIcon="true"
      @grid-ready="onGridReady"
      :animateRows="true"
      :rowBuffer="rowBuffer"
      :rowSelection="rowSelection"
      :rowModelType="rowModelType"
      :cacheBlockSize="cacheBlockSize"
      :cacheOverflowSize="cacheOverflowSize"
      :maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests="maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests"
      :maxBlocksInCache="maxBlocksInCache"
    >
    </ag-grid-vue>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";
import { reactive, onBeforeMount, ref } from "vue";
import TicketService from "@/services/TicketService.js";
export default {
  components: {
    AgGridVue,
  },
  setup() {
    const columnDefs = reactive({
      value: [
        {
          field: "brandId",
          sortable: true,
          cellRenderer: (params) => {
            if (params.value !== undefined) {
              return params.value;
            } else {
              return '<img src="https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/loading.gif">';
            }
          },
        },
        { field: "channel", sortable: true },
        { field: "channelReferenceId", sortable: true },
        { field: "createdOn", sortable: true },
        { field: "status", sortable: true },
        { field: "subject", sortable: true },
      ],
    });
    const gridApi = ref(null);
    const gridColumnApi = ref(null);
    const defaultColDef = {
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      flex: 1,
    };
    const rowBuffer = ref(null);
    const rowSelection = ref(null);
    const rowModelType = ref(null);
    const cacheBlockSize = ref(null);
    const cacheOverflowSize = ref(null);
    const maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests = ref(null);
    const maxBlocksInCache = ref(null);
    const icons = ref(null);
    rowBuffer.value = 0;
    rowSelection.value = "multiple";
    rowModelType.value = "infinite";
    cacheBlockSize.value = 20;
    cacheOverflowSize.value = 2;
    maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests.value = 1;
    maxBlocksInCache.value = 10;
    const dataSource = {
      getRows: (params) => {
        console.log("getting rows");
        TicketService.fetchTickets()
          .then(function (response) {
            params.successCallback(response.data.items, 100);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      },
    };
    const onGridReady = (params) => {
      gridApi.value = params.api;
      gridColumnApi.value = params.columnApi;
      params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
      params.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
    };
    onBeforeMount(() => {
      icons.value = {
        sortAscending: '<i class="fas fa-sort-alpha-down text-blue-400"></i>',
        sortDescending: '<i class="fas fa-sort-alpha-up text-blue-400"></i>',
        sortUnSort: '<i class="fas fa-sort text-blue-400"></i>',
      };
    });
    return {
      onGridReady,
      columnDefs,
      rowModelType,
      defaultColDef,
      icons,
      gridColumnApi,
      rowBuffer,
      rowSelection,
      cacheBlockSize,
      cacheOverflowSize,
      maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests,
      maxBlocksInCache,
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```